# making a local json into polar area chart on chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to make a chart from chart.js from a json file. But I have problems getting the file and parsing it into the data that I need in order to make a polar area chart.

When I searched for a code I was able to get this kind of html code

```
<body>
<input type="file">
    <script>
        let input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
        input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {

            console.log(e)

            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => {

                let json = JSON.parse(reader.result);
                console.log(json);

            };

            reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0], 'euc-kr')
            
        })

    </script>
</body>
```

I am trying to change this code so that it can use a json file from the same folder and connect it to chart.js

it would be great if I get some examples of the code that I need..